# tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat breaks tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample

Tags: tensorflow

With TF1.7 we added to our input pipeline the new tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat.
Our pipeline also uses tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample to balance our data set

Alas, when both are used - the balancing does not balance the DataSet. (It's not failing, but seems that it is not filtering the dataset as required)

After playing around with it, we concluded that we can not use the fused tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat and require to follow this protocol:

1. Repeat the dataset (dataset.repeat)
2. Balance the dataset:

   ```
   balanced_dataset = input_dataset.apply(rejection_resample(class_func=self.class_mapping_function,
                                                             target_dist=self.target_distribution)
                                          )
   balanced_dataset = balanced_dataset.map(lambda _, data: data)
   ```
3. Shuffle the dataset (dataset.shuffle)

I would like to use the new shuffle_and_repeat for performance reasons.
Any help will be much appreciated ! 
Maybe @mrry is familiar with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

@Shahar Karny, Im using TF1.8 and I'm experiencing the same issue - moreover, *rejection_resample* fails to do its resampling even when a **normal** *shuffle* is being used prior to it.

For example, **this works**:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x))
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample(class_func=lambda features, labels: labels, target_dist=tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], dtype=tf.float32)))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda _, data: (data))
```

And this **won't do the resampling**:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(filenames)) ### Added shuffling
dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x))
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.rejection_resample(class_func=lambda features, labels: labels, target_dist=tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], dtype=tf.float32)))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda _, data: (data))
```

As im doing the shuffling on the filenames, unfortunately I can't perform the shuffle after the resample, as mentioned above. I find this a bit odd as well.

Btw, for a really **skewed dataset**, this resampling technique can take significant time (I experienced **50x slowdown** then without resampling!)

Any suggestion on both issues?